# When does `Assembly.GetType(name)` return `null`?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I have a code like shown below

```
public static Type ToType(Type sType)
{    
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(SerializableType.AssemblyName);
    type = assembly.GetType(sType.Name);
}
```

**UPDATE**

In UI if I set value for base class no issues because their assembly creating normal way, but if you set value for user defined class their assembly creating different way like shown below

Comment: Can you give some sample data?  Might be helpful.  I'm pretty sure it's the namespace issue below, but want to make sure.

Comment: Maybe we should also ask, what is the problem this is trying to solve, we may know an easier solution as well...

Comment: I'm curious why take the `Type` to `XmlSerializableType` and back?  Why is this being done?  If we know why, perhaps we could suggest an easier way to perform the same task?  Or at least know more about why it can't find the class.

Comment: From Ui of our application we set one value, after saving that if we load the application again its returnig null setting in to a default value that was the root cause. While loading our application there are lot of process going on between server part and client part after completing certain event only we should pass request, but we are passing request early thats the reason

Comment: Does the assembly with the type have an auto-incrementing version property?  the `FullName` property of the assembly contains the version number, and if you are running from VS and rebuilding each time, you'd bump the version and the serialized type would not be able to load...

Comment: Unfortunately, a lot could be going on here, and it's difficult to determine from such a large example.  GetType() returns null if the type is not found in the assembly, but it's possible you could have a larger issue here.  Can you reproduce with a very simple example?

Comment: Is it throwing on Assembly.Load()?  Or on the GetType()? call, seems conflicting, but I could be reading it wrong.

Comment: I updated my question with a small example, is that sufficient?'

Comment: Well, I more meant small as in a self-sufficient peice of code that demonstrates the problem, such as Jon Skeet lays out in his "Writing the Perfect Question" post: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: What we're missing here is an example of a class you are trying to load, an example of the assembly info file showing the version, and an example of the strings for Name and Assembly so we can see if anything is wrong there.

Comment: one more thing when i posted my question first time i was trying to find the solution and removed some code did some manupualtion , in that scenario GetType() was the issue, but before removing the code and my work real issue was Assembly.Load() which will make to catch exception and becuse classed are not loaded

Comment: Ah, I see, so now `Assembly.Load()` is throwing?  What exception is being thrown?

Comment: example of userdefined class is Rounded Tree , example of assembly is _Rounded_TreeGOLD, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null ,

Comment: exception is "Could not load file or assembly '_rounded_treeGOLD, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"_rounded_treeGOLD, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nul" but here dont confuse assembly everything is there but in the line ObjectArray classes = GetObjectsByType(typeof(ManagedClass)); classes were not loaded thats why return null and throws exception

Comment: but here dont confuse assembly everything is there but in the line ObjectArray classes = GetObjectsByType(typeof(ManagedClass)); classes were not loaded thats why return null and throws

Comment: How big is this project, is there any way you could email it?  This problem sounds like it's a problem in the logic somewhere, it's not a problem with `GetType()` itself.

Comment: whats your email id i will send you related files

Comment: Never a good idea to post email addresses here :-) go to http://www.BlackRabbitCoder.net and click on the Contact link on the left, and send me a message using your email address, and I'll respond back with mine.  Otherwise if we post email addresses here in comments we may get spammed :-)

Comment: @James Michael Hare i will mail you

Comment: This is not working just because you load code from other assembly than you base class assembly. Trying to call this code from other assembly than contains definiton of searched type will result in type resolved to null.

It is reasonable, because you have to provide an assembly qualified type name, i.e. Type.AssemblyQualifiedName, not just type full name itself

If you derived classes defined elsewere in another assembly than base class with code sample, your code from assembly where base class is defined will not work.

Answer (score 8):

It returns `null` if the class name is not found, most likely because the `Name` property of your type just returns the type name, and not the namespace name to qualify it.  Make sure that your `Name` property includes the namespace qualifying it as well.

According to the MSDN on Assembly.GetType(string name), it returns:

> An object that represents the specified class, or Nothing if the class
>   is not found.

Thus since you're getting `null`, it couldn't find the type name, most likely reason is it's either misspelled, or you didn't prepend the type name with the namespace.

> This method only searches the current assembly instance. The name
>   parameter includes the namespace but not the assembly.

Or, it's also possible the case is wrong on the type name, there is a version of `GetType()` that supports a `bool` argument for a case-insensitive name compare as well.

p.s. The namespace is needed because the assembly name may not be an indicator of the namespace.  That is, if I had a type in an assembly `MySystem.MyClasses.DLL`, this does not mean that the type is necessarily in the `MySystem.MyClasses` namespace.

The full MSDN page (always good to see what things throw/return) is here: [Assembly.GetType Method(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx)

It's evident the assembly exists (or it would return `null` and you'd get a `NullReferenceException`), so another possibility is you don't have the same version of the assembly you are expecting (i.e. the program using this code has a different version of the assembly then the code generating the data).

Comment: but it doesnt have FullName property,, what you are talking about is it type.FullName??

Comment: @rickymartin: I corrected my post, I had a wrong assumption about what your `xmlSerializableType` was, can you verify that the `Name` property values you are seeing represent a fully qualified type name (i.e. something like System.Collections.ArrayList).

Comment: @rickymartin: In what context is this used?  Are these types returned across the wire through a service to a different machine?

Comment: i removed certain code after that only issue came , i posted the deleted code and the reason behind it

Comment: @rickymartin: Still unsure how you are using this.  Are you sending these serializable classes over a web service and another program on another machine is attempting to re-create them?  Or is this all in the same program?

Comment: until you provide AssemblyQualifiedName, instead of simply type name with namespace, you will get null, if you pass AssemblyQualifiedName you will get actual type.

Answer (score 0):

Your type may be non public, by default reflection only works on public types and members, unless you increase your level of security, type will be null.

Comment: `GetType()` can return non-public types from assemblies, you only run into potential issues if you attempt to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to find the correctly qualified name of a type in a dll I was trying to use, but found GetTypes() really useful in listing all available. In VB:

```
    Dim t As Type() = assem.GetTypes()
    Dim s As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To t.Length - 1
        s = s & t(i).FullName & vbCrLf
    Next i
    MsgBox(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an actual example from a UWP app.
The app namespace is My_App.  Class FooPage is under folder Views.  The way to get the Type is the following:

```
Type typePage = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("My_App.Views.FooPage}");
```

If you are not sure about the name of your type, use the following code to dump all classes and find the one of interest:

```
foreach(Type t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{t.Namespace}.{t.Name}");
}
```

Comment: This is working just because you did not load this code from other assembly than you definition assembly. Trying to call this code from other assembly will result in null. It is reasonable, because you have to provide an assembly qualified type name, i.e. Type.AssemblyQualifiedName, not just type name

Answer (score 0):

This is not working just because you load code from other assembly than you base class assembly. Trying to call this code from other assembly than contains definiton of searched type will result in type resolved to null.

It is reasonable, because you have to provide an assembly qualified type name, i.e. Type.AssemblyQualifiedName, not just type full name itself

If you derived classes defined elsewere in another assembly than base class with code sample, your code from assembly where base class is defined will not work.

This will work

---

```
public static Type ToType(Type type, ITypeResolver typeResolver)
{    
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(SerializableType.AssemblyName);
    type = typeResolver.GetType(assembly, sType.AssemblyQualifiedName);
}
```

You can use a TypeResolver like that (C# 7.2)

```
public interface ITypeResolver
{
    string GetName(Type type);
    Type GetType(Assembly assembly, string typeName);
}

class TypeResolver : ITypeResolver
{
    public string GetName(Type type) => type.AssemblyQualifiedName;
    public Type GetType(Assembly assembly, string typeName) =>
        assembly.GetType(typeName) ?? Type.GetType(typeName);
}
```

MSDN:

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netcore-2.1#System_Type_GetType_System_String_

Answer (score -1):

I guess you forgot to mention namespaces. The correct way would be

```
assembly.GetType(MyNameSpace+sType.Name)
```