# Why Type.GetType giving null?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does `Assembly.GetType(name)` return `null`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141190/when-does-assembly-gettypename-return-null)

In my project i have a base class named 'BaseSystem' and have derived class 'RoundedTree'. The code shown below `'type'` becoming null for derived class 'RoundedTree' and for baseclass 'BaseSystem' it is giving as '{`Name = "BaseSystem" FullName = "Root.SystemModel.BaseSystem"}'` .And the DLL i have is Root.SystemModel.dll and its version i can see in reflection as 3.6.7.8
What will be the reason behind 'type' becoming null forderived class

```
public static Type ToType(UserType usedType)
      {

         Type type = null;
         if (usedTypeType != null
            && usedTypeType.Name != string.Empty)
         {
            type = Type.GetType(usedType.Name);
```

Comment: did you abandon your previous attempt using Assembly.GetType()?  I never did get your code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141190/when-does-assembly-gettypename-return-null

Comment: Yes ,but now i have some different thought instead of fixing in leaf level fix issue in root level

Comment: here while loading application TypeBuilder myTypeBuilder i am getting as Name = "_RoundedTree" FullName = "_RoundedTree  in CreateType()  method , if i get this value in 'type' as type = Type.GetType(xmlSerializableType.Name);  then i believe all issue will go, i assumes

Answer (score 5):

[`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) will return null if you only give it the namespace-qualified type name (rather than the assembly-qualified one) and the type is in an assembly other than `mscorlib` and the currently executing one.

From the docs:

> If *typeName* includes the namespace but not the assembly name, this method searches only the calling object's assembly and Mscorlib.dll, in that order. If *typeName* is fully qualified with the partial or complete assembly name, this method searches in the specified assembly. If the assembly has a strong name, a complete assembly name is required.

Assuming your type is in a different assembly to the calling one, the options are:

- Get a reference to the `Assembly` in question and call `Assembly.GetType(string)`
- Give an assembly-qualified type name to `Type.GetType(string)`

Comment: the second option you told ,Give an assembly-qualified type name to Type.GetType(string), what does it mean .What here happening is while loading application it will create assembly for userdefined class and TypeBuilder myTypeBuilder as {Name = "_RoundedTree" FullName = "_RoundedTree"}  which as of now i am not getting for 'type = Type.GetType(xmlSerializableType.Name); '

Comment: @rickymartin: Well you haven't shown what `xmlSerializableType.Name` returns... doing so would help. Is the assembly created on disk? `Type.GetType(string)` is documented to only work reliably for assemblies on disk.

Comment: assembly is not there as dll for userdefined class but it is generating in our database xml file as __RoundedTreeMymachine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null 
xmlSerializableType.Name is _RoundedTree here

Comment: @rickymartin: Right, so `"_RoundedTree"` is *not* an assembly-qualified name. You need the full one with the assembly name, version etc.

Comment: while loading application TypeBuilder myTypeBuilder i am getting as Name = "_RoundedTree" FullName = "_RoundedTree in CreateType() method , if i get this value in 'type' as type = Type.GetType(xmlSerializableType.Name); then i believe all issue will go, i assumes

Comment: @rickymartin: Use `TypeBuilder.AssemblyQualifiedName`.

Comment: @rickymartin: Nope, should be there. It's an instance property of course, so: `string name = myTypeBuilder.AssemblyQualifiedName;`

Comment: okey, but again getting same assembly only ,So whats the usage of this , i need to get this value for 'type' which is of Type for proper working. Do i need to assign this string variable to any others

Comment: IF  Jon Skeet and  James Michael  dont hav answers , then i beleive problem is with my side, let me once again do an R&D for this issue

Comment: @rickymartin: I'm afraid I'm finding it very hard to understand your comments, and therefore your context. If you could produce a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, that would help a lot.